# Quill imports results in "missing dependencies" error

Tags: quill

We're attempting to upgrade to angular 11 and are finding that `Quill.import` results in errors:

```
An error occurred during the build:
Error: The target entry-point "@project/project-pattern-lib" has missing dependencies:
 - core/module
 - blots/block/embed
 - modules/clipboard
 - delta
 - formats/link

    at TargetedEntryPointFinder.findEntryPoints (D:\Dev\Git_project\project\node_modules\@angular\compiler-cli\ngcc\src\entry_point_finder\targeted_entry_point_finder.js:40:23)
    at D:\Dev\Git_project\project\node_modules\@angular\compiler-cli\ngcc\src\execution\analyze_entry_points.js:29:41
r.js:28:29)
    at SyncLocker.lock (D:\Dev\Git_project\project\node_modules\@angular\compiler-cli\ngcc\src\locking\sync_locker.js:34:24)
    at SingleProcessExecutorSync.execute (D:\Dev\Git_project\project\node_modules\@angular\compiler-cli\ngcc\src\execution\single_process_executor.js:57:27)
    at Object.mainNgcc (D:\Dev\Git_project\project\node_modules\@angular\compiler-cli\ngcc\src\main.js:74:25)
    at Object.process (D:\Dev\Git_project\project\node_modules\@angular\compiler-cli\ngcc\index.js:29:23)
    at NgccProcessor.processModule (D:\Dev\Git_project\project\node_modules\@ngtools\webpack\src\ngcc_processor.js:163:16)
    at D:\Dev\Git_project\project\node_modules\@ngtools\webpack\src\ivy\host.js:109:18
    at D:\Dev\Git_project\project\node_modules\@ngtools\webpack\src\ivy\host.js:39:24
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at Object.host.resolveModuleNames (D:\Dev\Git_project\project\node_modules\@ngtools\webpack\src\ivy\host.js:37:32)
    at actualResolveModuleNamesWorker (D:\Dev\Git_project\project\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:102904:133)
    at resolveModuleNamesWorker (D:\Dev\Git_project\project\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:103126:26)
    at resolveModuleNamesReusingOldState (D:\Dev\Git_project\project\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:103200:24)
 - core/module
 - blots/block/embed
 - modules/clipboard
 - delta
 - formats/link

See "C:\Users\Name\AppData\Local\Temp\ng-nIGMuY\angular-errors.log" for further details.
```

We can't seem to find anything in terms of a fix out there.  All of these "missing dependencies" are referenced in the code like:

```
import Quill from "quill";
const BlockEmbed = Quill.import(
  "blots/block/embed"
) as typeof Parchment.default.Embed;
```

Answer (score 5):

Figured out there is a weird syntax issue here and the following solves it:

```
const blockPath = 'blots/block/embed';
const BlockEmbed = Quill.import(blockPath);
```

Don't know why this fixes it.

Comment: Genious! Thank you!

Comment: Worked for me, I was wondering why though. My hunch is that the angular compiler looks for the syntax import('string') statically. But I'm not sure.

Comment: Seems like an Angular 11 specific bug.  We merged some code from Angular 12 to Angular 11 for a bug fix and ran into this bug instead.